# Number of Revenant Starting Disciplines

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I'm looking into playing a revenant in V:tR 2E at the moment (I have my reasons for not starting out a full Kindred) and I'm looking over the character creation process.

On page 81, it says, "Choose three dots of Disciplines. At least two must be in-clan disciplines."

On page 94, it says, "Revenants may only learn Disciplines out-of-clan and cannot learn clan-specific Disciplines without a teacher."

If my reading is correct, then a revenant can only take ONE starting Discipline dot as the other two are withheld waiting for an in-clan Discipline that isn't there yet, and a revenant starts out with less goodies than even a ghoul.

I am perfectly fine with that answer, especially if the two dots are held in reserve until I get a full embrace and are then free to be spent (which is my default interpretation),  but I wanted to check if I was correct on this before approaching my Story-Teller.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can have a backstory that grants you in clan dots, or gain it directly by feeding on vampires.

You are not bound to any clan, and so your costs for learning new disciplines are higher later on. However, your initial three dots are yours. From p81, say

> Consider how your character learned it. Did she have a mentor? Did she steal the blood of another clan.

You can gain the innate powers either by having a backstory with another mentor teaching you, or directly from the blood. You don't need a teacher, simply blood, and if you want a certain power you can just say someone taught you in your past.